# Change price variable based on a dropdown selection with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

**Problem:** How can i get the selected price from a dropdown menu and use it instead of the original price of the current product stored in the database?

**My approach:** I've been able to update a label with the selected price, but I still need to override the current price of the product. I'm pretty clueless right now.

*Additional information: The current price saved in the database is **$price** which need to be overridden by either **$prijshalf** or **$prijsheel** that are both also stored in the database.*

**The JQuery Code for updating the label:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown').change(function() {
                var price = 0;
                $('.dropdown').each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() != 0) {
                        price = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    }
                });
                $('#costLabel').text('€ ' + price.toFixed(2));
            });
        });
</script>
```

*This code block gets the value of the selected dropdown menu item and puts it in the label #costLabel*

**The PHP Code for rendering the products:**

```
$product_list = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = substr($row["product_name"],0,25);
         $price = $row["price"];
         $category = $row["category"];
         $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
         $beschrijving = substr($row["details"],0,25);
         $afbeelding = '<img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="50" height="50" />';
         $dropdown = $row["dropdown"];
         $dropdown2 = $row["dropdown2"];
         $prijshalf = $row["prijshalf"];
         $prijsheel = $row["prijsheel"];
         if($dropdown != "" || $dropdown2 != ""){
         $dropdownshow = "<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' class='dropdown'>
                                      <option name='prijshalf' value='$prijshalf'>$dropdown</option>
                                      <option name='prijsheel' value='$prijsheel'>$dropdown2</option>
                         </select>";
             }
         else{
                $dropdownshow = ""; 
         }
         $product_list .= "<div class='produkt'>
                           <div class='hardlopers'>
                           $afbeelding
                           <div class='subinfo'>
                           <span class='prijs-info'>Prijs:</span><span class='prijs'><label id='costLabel' name='costLabel'>$price</label>  </span>
                           <span class='productnaam'>$product_name</span>
                           <span class='dropdown'> 
                            $dropdownshow
                           </span>    
                           <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='homepage.php#redirect'>
                           <input type='hidden' name='pid' id='pid' value='$id' />
                           <input type='submit' name='button' id='button' value='' />
                           </form>
                           <span class='info'></span>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                           ";   

}

// Prints out the products to screen
echo $product_list;
```

Comment: So you're asking how you make an AJAX call to update the value in the database? You need to be more precise here.

Comment: @Jonast92 The value don't have to be updated. What i want to achieve is that on the dropdown selection it's using the $prijshalf or $prijsheel from the database instead of the $price value based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: @LarsMertens, what you want to do is to swap the `$price` with `$prijshalf` or `$prijsheel` on the dropdown selection but just in the html, not the database? Because it is not clear to me.

Comment: @Kstro21 $price should always stay the same but in some cases people can select to only buy half of an item with a price set for this too. In this case that is $prijshalf , this is stored in my database with a certain price for this item too, now when you add an item to the cart it is keeping the regular price but it should be $prijshalf when this is selected in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @LarsMertens, you almost get it, just need to decide how. I can't see how is your process of adding an item to the cart, so i can't tell you how. But you can try to put the dropdown in the `<form>` tag, later with php you get the value and if it is `prijshalf` or `prijsheel` do the math. The same with `js`, put the selected value of the dropdown in a `hidden` input within the `<form>`, send it to the server and do the math there. All is up to you. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kstro21 Thank you, i know what i'll have to do now to get this to work :) This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @LarsMertens i've created an answer so you can accept it if it really helped you and your question won't be listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how is your process of adding an item to the cart, so i can't tell you how. But you can try to move the dropdown into the `<form>` tag, later with php you get the value and if it is `prijshalf` or `prijsheel` do the math. The same with `js`, put the selected value of the dropdown in a hidden input within the `<form>` if you doesn't want the dropdown into the `<form>`, but i don't see why it shouldn't, send it to the server and do the math there. All is up to you.

Always use `js` just to show the info, always do the calculation and validation with `php` in the server for security reasons.

Happy coding